# Selectively populated vectors with substrings extracted from a source string

Tags: c++, vector, char

I have a char array, in which its contents look something like the following:

```
char buffer[] = "I1 I2 V1 V2 I3 V3 I4 DO V4";
```

As you may see, it's a typical blank separated character string. I want to put all sub-string(s) starting with a letter "I" into a vector (`IVector`), and sort its elements in ascending order. At the same time, I'd also want to put all sub-string(s) starting with a letter "V" into another vector (`VVector`), and sort its elements in ascending order. The other(s) (e.g. "DO" in this example) will be ignored.

I'm not familiar with STL algorithm library. Are there any functions to help me achieve the avove-mentioned job?

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use html-tags to format your question. Use the buttons above the edit field.

Comment: You might find this helpful if you are not familiar with the STL http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/STL%20Quick%20Reference%201.29.pdf

Comment: jmsu, thank you for your hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over all the substrings using an `std::istream_iterator<std::string>`:

```
std::stringstream s(buffer);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(s);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
for( ; begin != end; ++begin) {
    switch((*begin)[0]) { // switch on first character 
        // insert into appropriate vector here
    }
}
```

Then you can use `std::sort` to sort the vectors, as @Billy has already pointed out. You could also consider using an `std::set`, as that will always keep your items sorted in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, Space_C0wb0y. When I compile your code snippet, the following error occurred:1>f:\Test\test.cpp(74) : error C2676: binary '[' : 'std::istream_iterator<_Ty>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::string
1>        ]

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any functions to help me achieve the avove-mentioned job?

Yes. Have a look at `std::find` and `std::sort`.

Comment: Mr. Billy ONeal. Thank you! I'll google the two functions and try to use them to do my job.